# Sql server Linked server query error

Tags: multithreading, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010, linked-server

I am using a big stored procedure which is using many linked server queries. If i run this stored procedure manually it runs fine but if i call this stored procedure with exe using mufti-threading, it is raising "Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linkedserver1". and "Row handle referred to a deleted row or a row marked for deletion." for each execution. Performance of stored procedure is also very slow in comparison of same stored procedure without linked server queries. Please provide me some tips to improve performance of stored procedure and fix the issue mentioned above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are querying over linked servers, you will see a decrease in performance. Could it be possible that the procedures are affecting the same results - therefore giving you exceptions? If so you might be looking at dirty reads. Is that OK for your result set?

From the looks of it you seem to have to call the procedures sequentially and not in parallel. What you can do is cache the data on a server, and sync the updates etc, in batches.

Comment: Actually i using read uncommitted as transaction level. can this create such issue?

Comment: If the stored procedures are affecting the same records, it could be that you are getting a record which is waiting to be deleted, so yes it could be a possibility. Probably the reason why when executing sequentially you do not have the same problem.